# Addin Function, reference active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an addin which has 1 ribbon control, which performs a SQL statement on an Access DB and pastes the result, one cell to the right.  This works perfectly.  It is called SubTest(c as iribboncontrol) I also have another sub, called GetData(arg1,arg2) which I intended to use from the worksheet, as =GetData("01/02/2016","Open") and then one to the right again, the customised SQL returned is presented.  This all works ok, until the pasting `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rstData` works fine from the ribbon, but not from the function call, am I missing something simple.

Having get data, like so, still gives errors

```
public sub get_data()
     activecell.offset(1,1).value="TEST"
end sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: A function called from a cell as a worksheet function in itself cannot change the value of another cell or cells.

Comment: Cheers, I was hoping for something fancy to build ad-hoc queries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **function** takes inputs and *returns* a value. It cannot have *side-effects*<sup>1</sup>. Hence, you can't call a procedure that alters cell values inside a function that's called from a worksheet cell, [as Scott Craner already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869898/addin-function-reference-active-worksheet#comment68955427_40869898).

---

There are a number of things that are wrong with this though:

```
Public Sub get_data()
     ActiveCell.Offset(1,1).Value="TEST"
End Sub
```

Code that relies on `ActiveCell` means you have other code that uses `Select` and `Activate`. This makes your code extremely frail and error/bug prone, avoid them ([see how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)).

Avoid underscores in procedure names; use `PascalCase` instead. This isn't just "because it's convention" - VBA will refuse to compile more advanced code that has underscores in interface member names; so even if you don't ever use interfaces and the `Implements` keyword, make it a habit to avoid underscores in member names. In VBA the underscore has a special meaning, such as you can see in event handler procedures: `ObjectName_MemberName`, e.g. `Button1_Click`.

Name things for what they do. "get data" would be the name of a *function*, that "gets" a value [and returns it]. A `Sub` that "gets" something makes no sense. Your procedure doesn't "get" anything, it "sets" a value if anything.

---

<sup>1</sup> `Function` procedures called from VBA code can definitely have side-effects. The fact is, in an ideal world they *shouldn't*; use *procedures* for side-effecting code instead. Excel worksheet functions are *pure functions*, and user-defined functions are *required* to be more or less *pure functions* as well, else they simply can't be used in a worksheet. Take some input, compute a value, return that value: that's all a *function* does.